# Certain size from collection, including second filter with HQL?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I'm struggling with following scenario: Let's assume I have the two entities `Classroom` and `Member`, mapped with many-to-many. Classroom has the collection `Members`, containing the entities `Member`. 
I would like to get the classrooms which do have members of a certain count. That would result in something like:

`FROM Classroom cr WHERE cr.Members.size < 10`

Now I have a `Type` on Classroom. I'd like to filter first on Type, then the size. This won't work:

`FROM Classroom cr WHERE cr.Members.size < 10 AND cr.Members.Type = 1`

Results in: `illegal attempt to dereference collection`

How could I write such a query?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you need to do a join

```
from Classroom as cr left join cr.Members as m
where cr.Members.size < 10 and m.Type = 1
```

Comment: I also ended up with a join - unfortunately I have troubles with multiple Classrooms in the result despite of the use of `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer`. The whole query is much more complex than the above example (which would work like that I guess), so I am still trapped with post-process filtering, resulting in ugly lazy loads and performance issues).